# Is there a way to reassign an object value on the fly using destructuring in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, axios

```
const user = {}
user.fname = John
user.lname = Doe


axios.post({
    url,
    headers,
    params: user // but here I want to have the fname set to Jane instead of John
}).then(...).catch(...)
```

I know I can set it before, but I need to do it on the fly right when I use the object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the spread operator?

```
axios.post({
    url,
    headers,
    params: {
       ...user,
       fname: 'Jane' // but here I want to have the fname set to Jane instead of John
    }
}).then(...).catch(...)
```

You can also use `Object.assign` like:

```
Object.assign(user, { fname: 'Jane' })
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly ES6, because spread notation for *objects* is newer, but you can

```
axios.post({
    url,
    headers,
    params: { ...user, fname: 'Jane' }
}).then(...).catch(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spread syntax, to keep the other properties and overwrite the one you need:

```
const user = {}
user.fname = John
user.lname = Doe


axios.post({
    url,
    headers,
    params: {...user, fname: "Jane"} 
}).then(...).catch(...)
```